# Retrieving Local Translations from Metadata API call

Tags: metadata-api, translation, translation-workbench

I can successfully retrieve custom labels from my SOAP call to Salesforce Metadata API.
But what I need is the local translations which overrides my labels.

1. Are these translations are packaged or unpackaged (do i have to search them in my Managed package)
2. Which metadata type should i retrieve ?

   - Translations?
   - CustomLabelTranslation?
   - CustomObjectTranslation?

Here is a picture of my goal:

[image: What i'm trying to retrieve]

### Update

I'm writing Native iOS app which is using Salesforce SDK in it. I can successfully talk with Salesforce Metadata API. I just dont know which metadata object should retrieve in my RetrieveRequest,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe it's under the folders objectTranslations and translations and using the following types:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_translations.htm
http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_meta/Content/meta_customobjecttranslation.htm

If you include the following in your package.xml file used in the retrieve call you should fetch them:

```
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>CustomObjectTranslation</name>
</types>
<types>
    <members>*</members>
    <name>Translations</name>
</types>
```

Comment: Thanks.
I've managed to fetch translations with your answer but with minimal change. See code down below.

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>Translations</name>
    </types>
    <types>
        <members>*</members>
        <name>CustomLabels</name>
    </types>
    <version>30.0</version>
</Package>

Answer (score 3):

The Custom Label values coming from the managed package cannot be retrieved, but once they are overridden, they fall under the category of Local Translations / Overrides; now, by retrieving the Translation metadata type, you can access them.

Retrieving these Custom Labels (managed or unmanaged) and bulk updating their translations in any language is very simple using [Quick Update Translations](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/appxListingDetail?listingId=fa9afbfe-74ff-4027-ac32-2cdfd58184d3) AppExchange App. It also facilities bulk translation of entities like Custom Fields, Custom Applications, Custom Tabs, Validation Rules, and Custom Links/Buttons.

Disclaimer: I work at Satrang Technologies, the **Quick Update Translations** AppExchange App publisher.